# Testing a method that is called from another method

Tags: java

I have a `logon` method that calls `addUser`, another method in the same class.

We are having HS students code various methods and want them to be be able to test each method independently.  We have a JAR file without source code of all the methods fully coded (PROD class) and the students work on the same methods but in a DEV class.

Is there a way to use the DEV copy of `addUser` with the PROD methods to test if the application works with their implementation of `addUser`?

Comment: If you use an abstraction over `addUser` method, it'd be a lot simpler. Consider moving `addUser` outside the class and make the class to accept, e.g., a `UserAdder` interface that has an `addUser` method. Then ask the students to provide implementations for `UserAdder` interface and inject them into the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try subclassing, although it relies on the PROD class to be friendly (allow overriding of its methods).

```
class DEV extends PROD {
    @Override
    int addUser(String name) {
        ... students work and test this one implementation
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ... do my testing thing here, like for instance
        System.out.println("This is the expected result using PROD:");
        PROD prod = new PROD();
        int result = prod.logon();  // internally calls PROD.logon() and PROD.addUser()
        System.out.println(result);

        System.out.println("This is the test result using DEV:");
        DEV dev = new DEV();
        result = dev.logon();  // internally calls PROD.logon() and DEV.addUser()
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

This would work as follows:

To compile: `javac -classpath PROD.jar DEV.java`

To test: `java -classpath .;PROD.jar DEV`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  PROD is placed in a jar without source and the students already have access to all of its methods.  We have a PROD.logon() which calls PROD.addUser().  The students are rewriting all of  PROD as DEV.  If all they write is DEV.addUser() is there a way to test it using PROD?

Comment: See edited answer. The students will rely on PROD for the logon() call. Otherwise, if they rewrite the entirety of PROD (including logon()) they won't need it.